# Combining two event tables into one postgres view / timeline of events

Tags: postgresql, view, aggregate-functions, postgresql-9.4, materialized-views

I have two tables, `events` and `event_logs`.

The `events` table stores the theoretical data on a recurring event whereas the `event_log` stores specific information on a particular datetime.

## Event

```
+-----+---------------------------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id  | start_at                  | place_id | recurring_schedule                                                                        |
+-----+---------------------------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 358 | 2015-01-23 20:00:00 +0000 | 412      | {"validations":{"day":[2]},"rule_type":"IceCube::WeeklyRule","interval":1,"week_start":0} |
| 359 | 2016-01-22 19:30:00 +1100 | 414      | {"validations":{"day":[1]},"rule_type":"IceCube::WeeklyRule","interval":1,"week_start":0} |
| 360 | 2016-02-01 19:00:00 +1100 | 415      | {"validations":{"day":[4]},"rule_type":"IceCube::WeeklyRule","interval":1,"week_start":0} |
| 361 | 2016-02-01 20:00:00 +0000 | 416      | {"validations":{"day":[4]},"rule_type":"IceCube::WeeklyRule","interval":1,"week_start":0} |
| 362 | 2014-02-13 20:00:00 +0000 | 417      | {"validations":{"day":[2]},"rule_type":"IceCube::WeeklyRule","interval":1,"week_start":0} |
+-----+---------------------------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

- start_at (date time, used for the DOW and start time, actual date is ignored)
- recurring_schedule (weekly, bi-weekly, monthly), this is stored as a ruleset in a text column using IceCube but it could just have easily been stored as a column with 3 choices.

## Event_log

```
+-------+----------+----------+---------------------------+------------+
| id    | place_id | event_id | start_at                  | state      |
+-------+----------+----------+---------------------------+------------+
| 20600 | 58       | 35       | 2017-01-24 19:30:00 +0000 | completed  |
| 13236 | 105      | 94       | 2015-09-07 20:00:00 +0100 | pending    |
| 21388 | 311      | 269      | 2017-04-09 18:30:00 +0100 | failed     |
| 25265 | 23       | 45       | 2017-10-22 20:00:00 +0100 | incomplete |
| 25538 | 283      | 242      | 2017-11-07 19:30:00 +1100 | failed     |
+-------+----------+----------+---------------------------+------------+
```

The problem is reconciling recurring data with actual occurrences, data on the EventLog doesn’t exist, but for speed and necessity I would like to create some sort of aggregated view, eg `scheduled_events` (which looks and acts like the event_log) but which combines theoretical future events and their start times & dates with actually occurring EventLogs (when they exist).  But I’m unsure how to do this if someone has some suggestions.

Thanks,

Comment: are you looking for `outer join generate_series(time_in_future...`?..

Comment: Possibly, I'm just not sure how to combine theoretical dates with real ones (eg exceptions, etc.)

Comment: @VaoTsun I'm just not sure how to take events, use generate_series for all the specific wdays for each event that follow between two dates... then i could join it to the event_log table and manage the exceptions.

Comment: sorry - I'm a little swamped now for reading and comprehending the whole post. you can split it to simple short parts and look for solution. if there's no on SO - ask a shorter question. better have three small answered questions, then one that no one wants to dive into imho

Comment: good point, i'll try that.

Comment: and thanks for pointing me in the right direction too.